# FORTRAN logic notproblem

Tags: fortran

If I just use my function once, it works properly. If I make it do a loop like down below, the four lines of commented code, my code malfunctions. I can't really figure out why it will always return T or F for every other number after the initial value.

Asterisks are in the parenthesis of WRITE and READ but it doesn't show up here for some reason.

```
PROGRAM PRIME

INTEGER :: N = 0, i = 1,x = 0

LOGICAL :: IP

WRITE (*,*) "Enter a number:"

READ (*,*) N

!DO WHILE ( N < 1000)

IP = IsPrime(N)

WRITE (*,*) IP, N

!N = N + 1

!END DO

read(*,*) x

CONTAINS

FUNCTION IsPrime(N)

LOGICAL :: IsPrime

INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: N

IsPrime = .TRUE.

IF (N == 2) THEN

WRITE (*,*) N

ELSE 

DO WHILE (i <= (N/2))

   i = i + 2

   IF (mod(N,i) == 0) THEN 

   IsPrime = .FALSE.

   END IF

END DO

END IF


RETURN

END FUNCTION IsPrime

END PROGRAM PRIME
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're forgetting to reset `i` to 1 during each call to `IsPrime`.

The first time `IsPrime` is called, `i=1` from the top of `program main`. However, `i` is incremented during the first `IsPrime` call to something other than `1` so the second call starts with `i/=0`.

Note that because `IsPrime` is `contain`ed within `program main`, `IsPrime` inherits `i` from `program main`.

I'm also bound to remind you to use `implicit none` everywhere to avoid other errors, although it's not a problem in this case.

Comment: @WilliamBrown If you found the answer sufficient, please consider marking the answer accepted by pressing the green checkmark.